# Why cannot I type after I press ESC to close a window created by window.prompt()

Tags: javascript, html

Here is something interesting I find. Below are the repro steps:

1. In Chrome, go to any web page that has a input field, such as google.com
2. Go to your browser Console and execute the command `window.prompt("test")` to open a window
3. Close the console
4. Press Esc on the keyboard to close the window you just created;
5. Note that you won't be able to type anything in the input field until you close your tab and reopen it

I am wondering what's root cause of this issue and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is because focus that is lost is not automatically restored after a prompt is closed. If you're doing this on your own website, you can add code in the event listener for the prompt to re-focus the element on close. This way you can continue typing

Comment: Seems like a bug in Chromium. You could report it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).